# Simple Login screen with react-native on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am investigating react-native on Android and wish to implement a simple login screen.

I have managed to build the UI in my `index.android.js` file, as shown here:-

```
<View style={styles.container}>
<TextInput style={{height: 40, width : 300, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 8}}
        onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
        placeholder = 'Username'
        value={this.state.username}
        returnKeyType = {"next"}
        autoFocus = {true}
        onSubmitEditing={(event) => {this.refs.SecondInput.focus();}}/>
<TextInput style={{height: 40, width : 300, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 4}}
        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
        placeholder = 'Password'
        secureTextEntry={true}
        ref='SecondInput'
        value={this.state.password}/>
<TouchableHighlight style= {styles.submit}
        onPress = {this.onPressLoginButton.bind(this)}>
<Text>L O G I N</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
```

Whats the "Best Practice" for sending the entered username and password back to the Android Java code when my LOGIN button is clicked?

Currently I have created a custom `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` & `ReactPackage` to allow me to set the values back in the Android Application?

```
onPressLoginButton() {
    console.log("You tapped the button!");
    MyLogin.doLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password)
  }
```

UPDATE

My java code looks like this:-

```
@ReactMethod
public void doLogin(String username, String password) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "public void doLogin(String username, String password) {} username =" + username + " password = " + password);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "public void doLogin(String username, String password) {} mUsername =" + mUsername + " mPassword = " + mPassword);
    //doLogin(username, password);
}
```

and in my javascript I have this:-

```
var MyLogin  = NativeModules.MyLogin;
```

Is this "Best Practice" approach for communicating between react-native and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to know what method you implement on custom native module but let imagine you have a method named Login 
Using @ReactMethod annotation call the method and then call the method from javascript 
Look like this :

```
    @ReactMethod
    public void Login(String username,String password) {
      // Here what you trying to do
    if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
    // do this
        .....
    }
    }
```

and in javascript

```
NativeModules.CustomModule.Login("user","pass");
```

And don't forget to register custom module properly

Comment: I have updated my question, however short story: Yes I have done what you "Imagined".

Comment: I have a good imagination, now i see you change the question. are you looking for best approach?

Comment: yes, as I come from Android background (NOT RN or JS) I am looking for how to communicate between Android and RN, this is just one area I need assistance. I also wonder how to access my SQLite database from RN to fill  a ListView?

Comment: there are different API and service out there you can use but if you want codding purely this is a best solution i know

Comment: take a look at : https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-refreshable-listview